# Required specifications of "new design"s

Tags: patentability

I am really confused about this patenting procedure. specially I want to know besides the requirement that the "new idea" have to be original, **what specifications** do the "new idea"s and specifically "new design"s have to have, to be eligible for patenting?

Comment: What distinction are you making between "idea" and "design"?  There are things called design patents, they just have to do with the look of something. Do you mean that? Or actual inventions?

Comment: And by specifications do mean what level of detail must be presented?